# Meaning of `envelope` in context of time series

Tags: time-series, envelope

While checking TIMESAT, more specifically
http://web.nateko.lu.se/timesat/docs/TIMESAT33_SoftwareManual.pdf page 50, section 9.4 TSM_GUI.

Then I read:

*"The fits are affected by a number of options for detecting spikes, adapting to the upper envelope..."*

**What's the meaning of envelope?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In physics and engineering, the [envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(waves)) of an oscillating signal is a
>   smooth curve outlining its extremes. The envelope thus generalizes
>   the concept of a constant amplitude. The
>   envelope function may be a function of time, space, angle, or indeed
>   of any variable.

**Time Series without envelope**
[image: Time Series without envelope]

**Time Series with upper and lower envelope**
[image: Time Series with upper and lower envelope]

*Note: Images and more information can also be found [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/envelope.html)*